# Product Landing Page

Tags: html, css

I think I went overkill with trying to learn new ways to do the same thing, and this is as most as I could replicate the website from freecodecamp. I'd like advice on ways to do the same things in much easier ways and better overall.

```css
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    --bg-color: #EEEEEE;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

#header {
    /* Fixes the menubar at the top of the page */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

    /* Flex Container */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    /* other */
    padding-top: 2rem;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    z-index:1;

}

#header-img {
    width: 31rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

#nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 43%;

}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#center-box {
    margin: 6rem auto 0 auto;
    max-width: 100rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

#form {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#form * {
    height: 3rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#comment {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    transform: scaleY(1.2);
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#email {
    width: 27rem;
}


#submit {
    width: 15rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size:1.7rem;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #F1C40F;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    margin-bottom: 8rem;
}

#submit:hover, .product-select:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

#feature-container {
    display: block;
}

#feature-container li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 13rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.featuretitle {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    transform: scaleY(1.2);
}

.featuredesc {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
li#feature1 {
    background: url('feature1.png') left center no-repeat;
}

li#feature2 {
    background: url('feature2.png') left center no-repeat;
}

li#feature3 {
    background: url('feature3.png') left center no-repeat;
}

#video-container {
    display: block;
}

#video {
    height: 31.5rem;
    width: 56rem;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
}

#price-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 31rem;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.price-box {
    width: 31rem;
    height: 32rem;
    border: 0.01rem solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.price-box span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.product-title {
    height: 16.67%;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 140%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product-price {
    display: block;
    height: 16.67%;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    transform: scaleY(1.2)

}

.product-description {
    display: block;
    height: 45%;
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}

.product-select {
    height: 13%;
    width: 30%;
    font-size:1.7rem;
    background-color: #F1C40F;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
}

#end-banner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
}

#end-banner #links {
    width: 25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}

#end-banner #copyrights {
    color: #444;
    width: 25rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
    margin-top: 0.8%;
}

@media (max-width: 63rem) {
    .price-box {
        width: 32%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 50rem) {
    #price-container {
        height: 100rem;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .price-box {
        width: 30rem;
        height: 32rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 40rem) {
    #center-box {
        margin: 15rem auto 0 auto;
    }

    #nav-bar {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 37rem) {
    #video-container {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: calc((315/560)*100);
    }

    #video {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc((315/560)*100);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 34rem) {
    #header {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #header-img {
        padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .nav-link {
        padding-bottom: 0.8rem;
    }

    #feature-container {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #feature-container li {
        background: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: inherit;
    }

    .featuretitle {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .featuredesc {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> A Product Landing Page </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A Product Landing Page.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
        <header id="header">
            <img id="header-img"
            src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png">
            <nav id="nav-bar">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#center-box">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#video-container">How It Works</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#price-container">Pricing</a>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div id="center-box">
            <!-- The Form -->
            <form id="form" method='POST' action='https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit'>
                <p id="comment">Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</p>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                <input type="submit" name="email-submit" id="submit" value="GET STARTED">
            </form>
            <!-- The Features -->
            <ul id="feature-container">
                <li id='feature1'>
                    <span class='featuretitle'>Premium Materials</span>
                    <span class='featuredesc'>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</span>
                </li>
                <li id='feature2'>
                    <span class='featuretitle'>Fast Shipping</span>
                    <span class='featuredesc'>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</span>
                </li>
                <li id='feature3'>
                    <span class='featuretitle'>Quality Assurance</span>
                    <span class='featuredesc'>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- The Video -->
            <div id='video-container'>
                <iframe id="video"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y8Yv4pnO7qc?showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0"
                        title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </div>

            <!-- The Price Options -->
            <div id='price-container'>
                <div class='price-box'>
                    <span class='product-title'>Tenor Trombone</span>
                    <span class='product-price'>$600</span>
                    <span class='product-description'>Lorem ipsum.<br>Lorem ipsum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>Lorem ipsum.</span>
                    <input type="submit" name="product-select" class="product-select" value="SELECT">
                </div>
                <div class='price-box'>
                    <span class='product-title'>Bass Trombone</span>
                    <span class='product-price'>$900</span>
                    <span class='product-description'>Lorem ipsum.<br>Lorem ipsum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>Lorem ipsum.</span>
                    <input type="submit" name="product-select" class="product-select" value="SELECT">
                </div>
                <div class='price-box'>
                    <span class='product-title'>Valve Trombone</span>
                    <span class='product-price'>$1200</span>
                    <span class='product-description'>Plays similar to a Trumpet<br>Great for Jazz Bands<br>Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>Lorem ipsum.</span>
                    <input type="submit" name="product-select" class="product-select" value="SELECT">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Banner -->
            <div id='end-banner'>
                <div id="links">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Privacy</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Terms</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </div>
                <p id='copyrights'>Copyright 2016, Original Trombones</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```